# How to use Bluebird promises with Angular 5?

Tags: angular, promise, bluebird, zone.js

[Here's a link to the Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NhJQX19cVcC3TEoTzvLM)

I have a project within which the native `Promise` implementation is replaced with that of Bluebird. It is my understanding that in order to successfully use Angular 5 in this scenario, Bluebird must be patched in order to be made "zone aware." To accomplish this, I am following the instructions [shown here](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/NON-STANDARD-APIS.md#currently-supported-non-standard-common-apis).

This doesn't seem to work, though. Zone.js throws the following error:

> *Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*

Does anyone know the solution to this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [Patch for making the Bluebird library aware of Zone.js](https://gist.github.com/lorenzodallavecchia/d21684d5b7645df7e1dcd45642569004)?

Answer (score 0):

Newest version of zone.js have supported bluebird, please wait for the new version of zone.js (0.8.21).

https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/1039

About usage, you can find here.
https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/NON-STANDARD-APIS.md#currently-supported-non-standard-common-apis