# How to enable zone aware bluebird promises in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, bluebird, zone.js

I'm trying to make all the promises in my angular 8 project cancellable. When looking for a library to fulfill that need I found that [bluebird.js](http://bluebirdjs.com) looks *promising* ;-)

I then found and followed [these instructions](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/NON-STANDARD-APIS.md#currently-supported-non-standard-common-apis) on how to integrate bluebird with angular's zone aware promises. The reference expects the libs to be available as src in the `index.html`. So to copy the required javascripts files I put the following in my `angular.json`:

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "./node_modules/zone.js",
      "output": "./assets/zone.js/"
    },
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "./node_modules/bluebird",
      "output": "./assets/bluebird/"
    }
]
```

and in my `index.html` I added the following:

```html
  <script src="/assets/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/zone.js/dist/zone-bluebird.js"></script>
  <script>
    Zone[Zone['__symbol__']('bluebird')](Promise);
    Promise.config({cancellation: true});
  </script>
```

But unfortunately I just get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Bluebird.onPossiblyUnhandledRejection is not a function` when trying that.

If I don't import the scripts manually in my `index.html`, but instead move the code to my `main.ts`, I get the same error.

I tried changing the code in `main.ts` to the following:

```js
import { Promise as Bluebird } from 'bluebird';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-bluebird';
declare var Zone: any;
Zone[Zone['__symbol__']('bluebird')](Bluebird);
Bluebird.config({cancellation: true});
```

But that gives me the error `Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise (window|global) Promise has been overwritten.`

Any idea how to accomplish this or if it is possible at all with the currect versions of angular and zone.js?

Comment: I just stumbled across this open angular issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31724
Maybe that means, it just won't work right now?

Comment: This might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437776/how-to-use-bluebird-promises-with-angular-5

Comment: I will update the instruction later and post it here, the original one doesn't consider integration with angular cli.

Comment: @Allabakash Yeah, thanks - I've actually seen that, but the only answer to that question (from 2018) refers to it not being possible with `zone.js < 0.8.21`, but I'm trying it with the current version bundled with angular 8 and I'm still not succeeding.

Comment: @jialipassion That would be great - thanks in advance. I fact I've only tried it with `ng serve` so far - maybe this is something that only works for a prod build?

Answer (score 1):

I updated the document here.

Angular Usage:

in polyfills.ts, import zone-bluebird package.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-bluebird';
```

in main.ts, patch bluebird.

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then(_ => {
import('bluebird').then(Bluebird => {const Zone = (window as any)['Zone']; Zone[Zone['__symbol__']('bluebird')](Bluebird.default);});
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

After this, the Promise will become Bluebird, and Bluebird.then will be in angular zone.

please test and if there are any problems, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did (see my anwer below).
But yours is more precise, thank you!

I still don't know how to get cancelable async/await statements with angular though. (See the "sidenote" in my answer)

Comment: OK, I will check the async/await with Bluebird, BTW, Zone.js doesn't support native async/await. If you can provide a sample repo or sample code to describe the code not working will greatly help.

Comment: I've finally found a solution lending some code from `cancelable-awaiter` - Here's a working sample: https://github.com/itaysabato/cancelable-awaiter/issues/1#issuecomment-568804851 At least that's something to work with until https://github.com/tc39/proposal-cancellation resolves this for good. :-) Any input on how to improve my solution would still be much appreciated though!

Answer (score 0):

If I let things happen **after** bootstrapping angular, it works (I had always assumed that I tried to apply the "bluebird mode" too late, but apparently it was just too *early*):

```js
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(() => {
    Zone[Zone['__symbol__']('bluebird')](Bluebird);
    Bluebird.config({cancellation: true});
  })
```

---

**Sidenote** (not actually in the scope of the original question):
Sadly that still doesn't let me cancel async functions - only cancelling directly referenced Promises (now all Bluebirds) will actually call the `onCancel` callback.
For that I would need something like [cancelable-awaiter](https://github.com/itaysabato/cancelable-awaiter), but I can't get that to work with angular - see [the issue #1](https://github.com/itaysabato/cancelable-awaiter/issues/1) there.